# Permutations and Combinations confusing for my problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let me give an example, I have two vacuum chambers connected to each other. each vacuum chamber can be in one of 4 states, lets'say states a,b,c,d.

I am looking for the number of combinations that both chambers can be in together.

I use the formula 4 to the power of 2 (hence 4 states, and 2 chambers). This gives me 16 different combinations. What I don't want however, is a repetition of two same states together, example, a,b and b,a ; and c,d and d,c.

In this case I will have 10 different combinations.

What is the exact formula for such a problem? I have been looking at permutations and combination formulas , but they don't seem to give me what I need, unless I am missing something obvious. Is what i'm looking for a permutation , or a combination?

Thanks in advance for an answer, and sorry if my question is very basic for here. I'm not even a high school student, but sometimes the small problems twist our brains :)

Comment: @ Engineer999  Generalizing the answer of quasi: if you have $s$ states and $c$ chambers, and taking into account your restriction on repetition, the number of combinations is given by $\binom{s+1}{c}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want either two distinct states, or two equal states.

There are ${\large{\binom{4}{2}}}$ choices for distinct states, and ${\large{\binom{4}{1}}}$ choices for equal states, so the total count is
$$\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{1} = 6 + 4 = 10$$

Explanation:

> ${\large{\binom{4}{2}}}$ is the number of ways to choose a subset of $2$ objects from a set of $4$ distinct objects, which is the count you want for the case of distinct states.
>
> ${\large{\binom{4}{1}}}$ is the number of ways to choose $1$ object from a set of $4$ distinct objects, which is the count you want for the case of equal states.

So that's one way to conceptualize the count.

As an alternative, here's another way . . .

First count all ordered pairs: $4^2 = 16$.

Next, temporarily remove the pairs with equal states: $16 - 4 = 12$.

Next, divide by $2$ to correct the overcount: $12/2 = 6$.

Finally, add back the count for the pairs with equal states: $6 + 4 = 10$.

The more general scenario with $n$ indistinguishable chambers, and $k$ states, labeled $1,...,k$, can be approached this way . . .

For $1 \le i \le k$, let $x_i$ be the number of chambers in state $i$.

Then the number of distinct chamber-state systems is equal to the number of ordered $k$-tuples $(x_1,...,x_k)$ of nonnegative integers such that
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
Applying the stars-and-bars formula, the number of qualifying $k$-tuples is 
$$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$
For example, with $2$ chambers and $4$ states, we have $n = 2$, and $k=4$, so the number of distinct systems is 
$$\binom{2+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{5}{3} = 10$$
as expected.

Comment: Thanks. So what's the general formula? If I have more than 2 chambers , for example 3, and more states...

Comment: @Engineer999: I edited in an analysis for the more general scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference between combinations and permutations?

Combinations are the ways you can group a set of items, in an unordered fashion. Permutations are the ways you can order a group of items.
What this means is, calculating the combinations WILL give you the (a,b),(b,c),(a,c) that you're looking for, while permutations will give you (a,b), as well as (b,a).

How to calculate them both?

You have two variables: the number of things to choose from, and the number of things you can choose at one time. We'll call the number of things to choose from (4 states in your case) the variable n, and we'll call the number of things you can choose at one time (2 chambers) the variable k.

To calculate the permutations, use this formula:
P(n,k) = n!/(n-k)!

To calculate combinations use this formula:
C(n,k) = n!/[(n-k)!*k!] = P(n,k)/k!

If you have any further questions, this is one of my favorite explanations on the web: https://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/

Comment: The combinations formula is not giving me 10 tho, as expected?